# NSIS import PowerShell module with parameters

Tags: nsis, powershell-4.0

I have written a sample program that will write `Hello World` and created `NSIS` file and executed which works fine for me

My `.nsi` script goes as follows

```
!include "x64.nsh"

Name "nsExec Test"
OutFile "nsExecTest.exe"
#ShowInstDetails show

Section "Output to variable"
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "Import-Module C:\PowerShell\Hello.psm1"'
Pop $0
Pop $1
DetailPrint '"ImportModules" printed: $1'
SectionEnd
```

Which is printing the write host as per written when I executed it

My code in `.psm1` file

```
# Filename: Hello.psm1
Write-Host
Write-Host 'Hello World!'
Write-Host "Good-bye World! `n"
# end of script
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same with parameters, can some one help me

```
# Filename: TestParameter.psm1
function TestParam([string] $TestParam)
{
    Write-Host
    Write-Host '$TestParam'
    Write-Host "Good-bye $TestParam! `n"
}
# end of script
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a module, how about using a plain script?

In `C:\PowerShell\script1.ps1`:

```
param([string]$TestParam)

Write-Host
Write-Host '$TestParam'
Write-Host "Good-bye $TestParam! `n"
```

And then in the `nsi`:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell.exe "& "C:\PowerShell\script.ps1 -TestParam myString"'
```

Comment: But mine is Module file, so how can I do that

Comment: Didn't worked when I make it as script to execute, `"ImportModules" printed: Import-Module : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
'TestParam'.
At line:1 char:58
+ ... rt-Module C:\PowerShell\TestParameter.ps1 -TestParam Hello-W ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterB 
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
   ands.ImportModuleCommand
 Completed
`

Comment: @Dotnet Don't use the `Import-Module` cmdlet, I deliberately removed it from the example in my answer

Comment: Even I couldn't call a function with out having parameter